# Populating QVector from QList

Tags: qt, qt4, qlist, qvector

I have a QList and QVector. I populate Qlist and then tried to copy to QVector. Ovector has a [fromList()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvector.html#fromList) method. But it do not work.

My code :

```
QList<int> listA;
QVector<int> vectorA; //I also tried QVector<int>vectorA(100);

for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    listA.append(i);
}

vectorA.fromList(listA);
```

After this code vectorA returns empty

I use Qt 4.8.5 under Linux

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should write:

```
vectorA = QVector::fromList(listA);
```

as [`fromList`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvector.html#fromList) is a static method of the class `QVector`.

The code you wrote create a `QVector` from `listA` but as you do not store it in some variable using the assignment operator or use it through a function call for instance, the QVector is dropped. Either way, vectorA remains empty.

Alternatively, you can use [`QList::toVector`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#toVector) the following way:

```
vectorA = listA.toVector();
```

Comment: I had to also add the template definition to the static method for it to work:   QVector<T>::fromList(list)