# Efficient curve plotting using QwtPlotCurve

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwt

I have a code base that plots many scope-like curves using QT library. We are trying to optimize the running time of this application (because we reached the wall on CPU usage). After some profiling I found that the main data plot loop calls this function from QWT library:

```
void QwtPlotCurve::setSamples( const QVector<double> &xData, const QVector<double> &yData )
{
    setData( new QwtPointArrayData( xData, yData ) );
}
```

This is done every 100ms. As a result, every 100ms there is a `new` call for `QwtPointArrayData` object, then there is a `delete` call for the previous version of the `QwtPointArrayData` object, for every curve on every scope.

My question is: is there a better more efficient way to plot data without re-allocating it on every update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory allocation can cause a severe bottleneck in any program, depending on how often it is called. It is a very expensive instruction in terms of performance and one should always desing an architecture, such that this doesn't occur. 
There are many better ways, you absolutely don't need to re-allocate new memory for `QwtPointArrayData`. Take a look at the examples of qwt library, such as **oscilloscope** or **realtime**. Basically you can use a `QwtDirectPainter` and its function `drawSeries`, which requires as arguments a QPlotCurve  and the number of samples you wish to draw.

https://qwt.sourceforge.io/class_qwt_plot_direct_painter.html

Of course you have to set the samples of the curve through setSamples() or setRawSamples instruction

https://qwt.sourceforge.io/class_qwt_plot_curve.html#aa51cd3fa00f2a046ca5a9889c5db2413

This is a very efficient approach. But again, go to the folder **examples** of the library to find **oscilloscope** and **realtime** examples, and study the library itself, as there are might be other approaches that could suit you better.

EDIT: 
I didn't understand at first that this was a code snippet from the library. I think you should try setRawSamples instead, as it should be more efficient https://qwt.sourceforge.io/class_qwt_plot_curve.html#afd13c94e23520dacbc37b4d0fd036a8b

Comment: Thank you @danmar. I'll try `setRawSamples`. It does, however, comes with a drawback that I will have to keep the raw arrays alive for the duration of the plot (and the program). If I keep adding new data to the end of the array, in order to clear data from the front I will have to copy all data one element every time.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, since you are using **QVector** class, which features instructions such as remove(int) or removeFirst()  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#removeFirst

Comment: The problem is that `QVector::removeFirst()` is that it will have to move and possibly dynamically reallocate the data inside the vector to make sure that `[0]` still returns the first element and `QVector::constData()` returns a contiguous array.

Comment: Well yes, data reallocation does happen, at least according to the docs of **QVector**. Perhaps you could consider using a dynamical approach for storing samples, such as a class **QList**, as this class introducess less overhead when adding/deleting/moving elements of a vector. However, then in order to plot, you would have to convert the **QList** vector to **QVector** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569873/populating-qvector-from-qlist